# How to find aliases in Global Jest setup?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I want to run some stuff only once before all test cases. Therefore, I have created a global function and specified the **globalSetup** field in the jest configuration:

```
globalSetup: path.resolve(srcPath, 'TestUtils', 'globalSetup.ts'),
```

However, within **globalSetup**, I use some aliases @ and Jest complains it does not find them.

How can I run **globalSetup** once the aliases have been sorted out?

My Jest configuration is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  rootDir: rootPath,
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  setupFiles: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'env.testing.ts')],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [path.resolve(srcPath, 'TestUtils', 'testSetup.ts')],
  globalSetup: path.resolve(srcPath, 'TestUtils', 'globalSetup.ts'),
  globals: {},
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'json'],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>/' })
};
```

When I run **testSetup** before every test, it runs ok the aliases, but this does not happen with **globalSetup**.

Any clue what could I do?

Comment: Please give a [mre] including the relevant code and error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I have found there is no solution for this based on the comments on this issue:
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6048

The summary is that globalSetup runs outside of Jest ecosystem and therefore it will not recognize the aliases, etc.

There are several workarounds, for example, if your npm run test command is something like this:

```
"test": "jest --config config/jest.config.js --detectOpenHandles --forceExit"
```

Then you can do something like:

```
"test": "node whateverBeforeJest.js && jest --config config/jest.config.js --detectOpenHandles --forceExit"
```

Answer (score 6):

I managed to get this work by including `tsconfig-paths/register` at the top of my globalSetup file:

```
// myGlobalSetupFile.ts

import 'tsconfig-paths/register';
import { Thing } from './place-with-aliases';

export default async () => {
  await Thing.doGlobalSetup();
}
```

You have to make sure you have `tsconfig-paths` installed in your project.

Comment: This should be marked as the selected answer! Was very helpful for me. Thanks!

Comment: This should definitely be the right answer genius!

Answer (score 0):

Javier is right that globalSetup runs outside of the Jest ecosystem and will not recognize the aliases.

But I solved the problem this way:

Folder Structure:

```
src
└── __tests__
    └── client 
    └── server
        └── tsconfig.json
        └── _config
            └── jest.config.ts
            └── jest.global.setup.ts
            └── jest.global.teardown.ts
        └── controllers
            └── public.test.ts
            └── ...more
└── client
    └── ...more
└── server
    └── controllers
    └── ...more
└── tsconfig-base.json
package.json
```

package.json

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "supertest": "^6.3.4",
        "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
        "typescript": "^5.4.2",
        ...
    },
    "_moduleAliases": {
        "@/controllers": "bin/controllers",
        "@/enums": "bin/enums",
        "@/exceptions": "bin/exceptions",
        "@/interfaces": "bin/interfaces"
    },
    ...
}
```

tsconfig-base.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2020",
        "types": ["node", "jest"],
        "composite": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        //"traceResolution": true,
    },
    "include": [
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "**/node_modules/*",
        "bin",
        "public"
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig-base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "NodeNext",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "rootDir": "../..",
        "outDir": "../../../bintests",

        "paths": {
            "@/controllers/*": ["../../server/controllers/*"],
            "@/enums/*": ["../../server/enums/*"],
            "@/exceptions/*": ["../../server/exceptions/*"],
            "@/interfaces/*": ["../../server/interfaces/*"]
        },
    },
    "include": [
        "**/next-env.d.ts",
        "**/*.ts",
        "../../server/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "**/node_modules/*",
        "bin",
        "public"
    ]
}
```

jest.config.ts

```
import _path from 'path';
import type { Config } from '@jest/types';
import { pathsToModuleNameMapper } from 'ts-jest';

const testsSrc: string = _path.resolve(__dirname, '../..');
const serverSrc: string = _path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../server');

export const aliases: any = {
    '@/controllers/*': [`${serverSrc}/controllers/*`],
    '@/enums/*': [`${serverSrc}/enums/*`],
    '@/exceptions/*': [`${serverSrc}/exceptions/*`],
    '@/interfaces/*': [`${serverSrc}/interfaces/*`],
};

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
    rootDir: `${testsSrc}/server`,
    roots: ['<rootDir>'],
    testMatch: [
        //'**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)',
        '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)',
    ],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
    },

    preset: 'ts-jest',
    //'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    verbose: true,
    automock: false,
    globalSetup: '<rootDir>/_config/jest.global.setup.ts',
    globalTeardown: '<rootDir>/_config/jest.global.teardown.ts',

    modulePaths: [serverSrc], // <-- This will be set to 'baseUrl' value
    moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(aliases /* ,{ prefix: '<rootDir>/' } */),
};

export default config;
```

jest.global.setup.ts

```
import _path from 'path';
import * as TSConfigPaths from 'tsconfig-paths';
import { aliases } from './jest.config';

const baseUrl: string = _path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
// @ts-ignore: TS6133
const cleanup: () => void = TSConfigPaths.register({
    baseUrl,
    paths: aliases, // tsConfig.compilerOptions.paths,
});

import ExpressApp from '@/controllers/express-server';
import PublicController from '@/controllers/public';

export const globalSetup: () => Promise<void>
    = async (): Promise<void> => {

        const expressApp: ExpressApp | null = new ExpressApp();
        expressApp?.initializeControllers([
            new PublicController(expressApp),
        ]);

        (globalThis as any).__ExpressApp__ = expressApp;

    };

// afterAll(async (): Promise<void> => {
// });

export default globalSetup;
```

And finally, public.test.ts

```
import request from 'supertest';
import express from 'express';
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';

import ExpressApp from '@/controllers/express-server';

describe('public.test.ts', () => {

    //let agent: request.Agent;
    //let tmp: any = null;

    beforeAll(async (): Promise<void> => {
        ExpressApp.me = (globalThis as any).__ExpressApp__;
        //agent = request.agent(ExpressApp.me?.app || undefined);
    });

    test('get /public/v1/version', async (): Promise<void> => {
        const expressApp: ExpressApp | null = ExpressApp.me;
        const response: any = await request(expressApp?.app as express.Application)
            .get('/public/v1/version');
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(StatusCodes.OK);
        expect(response.body).toBe('1.0.0.0');
    });

});
```